# Are sessions and/or cookies used in desktop applications?

Tags: desktop-application

In web applications, we often use sessions or cookies in login systems. Now, regarding desktop applications, I wonder if sessions or cookies are used. It seems obvious that yes, but I would like to clarify this doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are used. Imagine Steam. You can start/end your session in the desktop application and if you choose to remember the user, your session stays active every time you turn on your computer.